# How to change date and time of a remote computer

Tags: windows-xp, windows-domain, date-time

How to change **date and time** of a remote computer that runs **windows XP** on a 2008 domain?
because that client failed to log on local or from remote desktop with below message:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can log in as a **local** Administrator. Try entering `kamali-pc\Administrator` or `Administrator@kamali-pc` as the username. If the account is *still* unavailable, reboot in Safe Mode, which always activates the local Admin account.

Comment: thanks for your answer, but problem is I'm not at customer site, and in client side local admin password is blank, so client don't allow me to have remote desktop with blank password. that's why I want to remotely change date and time.

Comment: @Kaveh: It doesn't matter if you try this using Remote Desktop or any other protocol – they all use the same login checks, and the same problem will happen. If you can't remotely log in over RDP, you can't remotely log in over any other Windows protocol that would let you set the clock.